# Always getting same result from webservice in windows app 8.1 c#?

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-phone-8.1, async-await

I'm working on windows app 8.1 Notification c# I had written one async method. I had also created scheduler for async method which is calling this method on every 5sec.

My problem is I always getting old records even if my webservice returns new records. If I close my application and start again then i am able to see the latest records.

My Webservice method returns json data.

```
private int timesTicked = 1;
private int timesToTick = 10;

public NotificationPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    // this._channelUri = LocalSettingsLoad(ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings, ChannelUriKey, ChannelUriDefault);
    Task<string> getURi = UpdateChannelUri();

    DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000) };
    timer.Tick += (s, e) =>
    {
        getNotificationFrom_Api();

    };
    timer.Start();
}

private async void getNotificationFrom_Api()
{

    try
    {
        string uri = "http://abc/service1.svc/GetNotificationList"; //testing purpose
        HttpClient http = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
        HttpResponseMessage response = await http.GetAsync(uri);
        var webresponse = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;


        var emp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClNotification>(webresponse);
        ListBox1.ItemsSource = emp.GetNotificationlistResult.ToList();

    }
    catch (Exception rt)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly if you are in ASP doing a .Result is generally a bad idea because you are at risk of getting thread deadlocks: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

So I'd change this line too:

```
  var webresponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

If it is an HTTP GET it could be that the results are being cached at a proxy or by your browser. To prevent this you can set the HTTP Headers to prevent caching:
http://www.mobify.com/blog/beginners-guide-to-http-cache-headers/

Comment: i tried above still getting same result but how should i clear cache in my code

Comment: do i need to handle cache in my webservice or in my c# method

Answer (score 1):

If anybody on the same boat just add below line:

```
HttpClient http = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
```